# SSL_write not failing though remote end is down

Tags: c++, linux, ssl, tcp, openssl

I'm using an ssl connection on which i write using SSL_write. If I close the other end of this connection SSL_write returns the number of bytes that I write instead of -1. For the next write it returns -1 but it's too late, I wanted to know this information from the first packet.
For the server I am using

```
openssl s_server -accept 1115 -cert ~/.cert/cert.pem -key ~/.cert/key.pem
```

To test I send 3 packets with 5 seconds window between each packet. If I kill s_server before sending the second packet, SSL_write returns positive number for the second packet and -1 for the third. The client is written is C. The whole app is more complex but what I basically do is:

```
/* connection init */
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,1,...);
connect(sock, ...);

ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());
SSL_CTX_set_mode(ctx, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2|SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3);
ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd);
SSL_connect(ssl);

/* and in the write function */
SSL_write(ssl, buffer, len);
```

I am using openssl 1.0.2g on Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia. Any reason for SSL_write not to return -1 the moment the remote end is dead? My only idea to fix this was to enable keepalive but it didn't work.

Comment: OpenSSL buffers data, so it might not even go to the network yet on the first write, and so would not see a network error yet. A subsequent write may flush the buffer to network, at which time the error is detected. In fact, even without SSL, a simple `write()`/`send()` could suffer from the same issue due to OS kernel buffering. In general, if a write operation succeeds, it just means data was accepted for *eventual* transmission, it is not guaranteed that the data has *actually* been transmitted yet. That happens in the background.

Comment: Tried to use TCP_NODELAY option on the TCP socket to disable nagle but with no success. Will look for similar options openssl API.

Comment: Used a buffer of ~5Kb to avoid any kind of buffering still have the same issue so I don't think that's the problem.